# integrate skype for business with my web app

Tags: javascript

I want to integrate skype for business with my web app, just want to open the app on button click.

There is a way to open a chat window with some specific user via below line in js:

```
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="im:<sip:"+textEmail+">";
```

but i want to only open the app and land on the home screen of the app and not to initate any chat.

Comment: If you’re not using Skype for Business to do anything, what’s the point of having your site open it…? Why wouldn’t your users just want to open it themselves? Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case to ensure this isn’t an XY problem?

Comment: Note that if I type `im:` in my browser, it asks me which Instant Messaging app to open, with options "Teams", "Skype for Business", and "Look for app in Microsoft Store". From this it seems that the protocol `im:` is not guaranteed to be bound to Skype; it will depend on the settings of the user & what software they have installed, if anything.

Comment: @esqew thats the very same question i asked from my seniors, but the response was "please dont think why is it required, its required thats it"

Comment: @Peter B, the system where the app will be used it a client virtual system so everyone will only have skype for business installed and nothing else.. so that is not an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by setting `textEmail` to *the user's own email address*.

For example, if your application **knows** that the user is using SfB address `john.doe@domain.com`, then this should (could?) open SfB on the starting page:

```
const textEmail = "john.doe@domain.com";
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="im:<sip:" + textEmail + ">";
```

Presumably this happens because they can't chat with themselves, and no error is shown - or at least that is what happens for me; your mileage may vary.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, it opened a new outlook message addressing to user's id itself(for some reason), for all other user id's it opens the chat window

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference#startswitch-focus-to-the-skype-client) you have to use `skype:`, not `im:`.

Also to simply activate Skype, you should leave empty action.

```
document.getElementById('skypeChat').href="skype:";
```

Comment: I have already tried ur suggestion but it is not working, and the im:sip tag is a working code, but it opens the chat window with the subjected user i only want to open the skype home page. Also note it is skype for business and not normal skype.